# How to use name="array[]" on forms in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a structure like this

```
$scope.mydata = {
 'attribute': 'value',
 'otheratribute'  : 'othervalue',
 'thirdatribute' : {
      'name': 'xx',
      'desc': 'yy'
  }
}
```

and input to the `thirdatribute` like this

```
<form name="myForm">
  <div ng-class="{ 'has-error': myForm.thirdatribute.name.$invalid }">
    <span>My subdata</span>

    <input name="thirdatribute['name']" type="text" 
           ng-model="mydata.thirdatribute.name" required>

  </div>
</form>
```

the root atributes `attribute` and `otheratribute` validation work fine but the `thirdatribute` throw an error on console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '$invalid' of undefined
```

some idea that i can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can name that input "thirdatributename" instead of what you currently have. The input name is what's used in the form object and doesn't have to match the ng-model name.

```
<div class="form-group row" ng-class="{ 'has-error': myForm.thirdatributename.$invalid }">
  <span class="col-md-2 control-label text-left">My subdata</span>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control "
      ng-model="mydata.thirdatribute.name"
      required
      name="thirdatributename"
      />
  </div>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/qdeJM2GUYyjmXdcYSBQ7?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, it work for me! The 'name' attribute don´t need follow the same model structure, right?

Comment: That's correct - the name attribute doesn't need to follow the model structure...it's just how you reference that model object's validation in the form.

Answer (score 1):

I find these functions useful, you can name inputs anything, and use form.thosenames  for 'ngModelContoller' to call these functions

```
$scope.getCssClasses = function(ngModelContoller) {
            return {
              error: ngModelContoller.$invalid && ngModelContoller.$dirty,
              success: ngModelContoller.$valid && ngModelContoller.$dirty
            };
          };

 $scope.showError = function(ngModelController, error) {
         return ngModelController.$error[error];
    };
```

and here in HTML

```
<div class="control-group" class="getCssClasses(form.email)">
      <span ng-show="showError(form.email, 'email')" >You must enter a valid email</span>
     </div>
```